# Use ROW_NUMBER() OVER() with subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some T-SQL script that I need to make a ROW_NUMBER OVER() when my FROM table is a subquery.

It is forbiden in the SQL Server?

See the example below.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PATIENTALERT_ID ORDER BY SOURCE_TIME) AS RN 
        FROM (SELECT 
                MIN(PATIENTALERT_SAMPLE_ID) AS PATIENTALERT_SAMPLE_ID, 
                PATIENTALERT_ID, SOURCE_TIME, TEXT 
            FROM 
                PATIENTALERT_SAMPLE
            GROUP BY 
                PATIENTALERT_ID, SOURCE_TIME, TEXT)
```

The error result is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Thank you for any suport

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is completely unrelated to your `ROW_NUMBER`. The issue is that you need to add an alias to the derived table:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PATIENTALERT_ID ORDER BY SOURCE_TIME) AS RN 
        FROM (SELECT 
                MIN(PATIENTALERT_SAMPLE_ID) AS PATIENTALERT_SAMPLE_ID, 
                PATIENTALERT_ID, SOURCE_TIME, TEXT 
            FROM 
                PATIENTALERT_SAMPLE
            GROUP BY 
                PATIENTALERT_ID, SOURCE_TIME, TEXT) AS T;
```

Comment: Hi Lamak thank you for you help, problem solved with your answer!